# data getting moved instead of added

Tags: c#, asp.net, entities

I am trying to create functionality to copy data from one order to another. Here is the code that copies the data:

```
 protected void copySeminarIDButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //show some message incase validation failed and return
            String seminarID = this.copySeminarIDText.Text;
            Int32 id;
            try
            {
                id = Convert.ToInt32(seminarID);
            } catch (Exception e2)
            {
                return;
            }

            //copy over all the registration types now for the entered id
            using (SeminarGroupEntities db = new SeminarGroupEntities())
            {
                var seminars = db.seminars.Where(x => x.id == id);
                if (seminars.Any())
                {
                    var s = seminars.First();

                    //Load RegTypes
                    try
                    {
                        var regList = s.seminar_registration_type
                            .OrderBy(x => x.sort)
                            .ToList()
                            .Select(x => new seminarRegistrationTypeListing
                            {
                                id = x.id,
                                amount = x.amount,
                                description = x.description,
                                feeTypeId = x.feeTypeId,
                                method = x.method,
                                promoCodes = PromoCodesToString(x.xref_reg_type_promo.Select(z => z.promoId).ToList()),
                                title = x.title,
                                isPreorder = x.isPreorder,
                                sort = x.sort
                            });

                        this.dlTypes.DataSource = regList;
                        this.dlTypes.DataBind();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Response.Write("RegTypes: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                } else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception m)
        {

        }
    }
```

The user will enter a `ID` of the invoice they want to copy from. The above code copies pull the right data from the invoice and loads it on the page. When i click save the data is being saved.

The problem that is occurring is that the invoice that i copy data from will no longer have the data any more. So basically instead of copying the data its actually moving the data to the new invoice. I want to copy.

Here is my `Save` code.

```
        private void SaveRegTypes(int seminarId)
    {
        //Reg Types
        using (SeminarGroupEntities db = new SeminarGroupEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var s = db.seminars.Where(x => x.id == seminarId).First();
                var msg = "alert('Saving:" + seminarId + "');";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "Data Copied...", msg, true);
                this.copySeminarIDText.Text = msg;

                //s.seminar_registration_type.Clear();
                foreach (DataListItem dli in this.dlTypes.Items)
                {
                    String sId = ((HiddenField)dli.FindControl("hdnId")).Value;
                    var reg = new seminar_registration_type();
                    if ((sId != "") && (sId != "0"))
                    {
                        Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(sId);
                        reg = db.seminar_registration_type.Where(x => x.id == id).Single();
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "Data Copied...", "alert('hidded field id is empty.');", true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        db.seminar_registration_type.Add(reg);
                    }

                    reg.feeTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(((DropDownList)dli.FindControl("ddlRegType")).SelectedItem.Value);
                    reg.amount = Convert.ToDecimal(((TextBox)dli.FindControl("txtPrice")).Text);
                    reg.title = ((DropDownList)dli.FindControl("ddlRegType")).SelectedItem.Text;
                    reg.description = ((TextBox)dli.FindControl("txtRegDesc")).Text;
                    reg.method = Convert.ToInt32(((DropDownList)dli.FindControl("ddlDeliveryMethod")).Text);
                    reg.promocode = null;
                    reg.isPreorder = Convert.ToBoolean(((CheckBox)dli.FindControl("chkPreorder")).Checked);
                    reg.sort = 1;
                    reg.seminarId = seminarId;

                    string sort = ((TextBox)dli.FindControl("txtRTSort")).Text;
                    try
                    {
                        reg.sort = Convert.ToInt32(sort);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { }

                    //Do Promo Codes


                    Repeater rptPromocodes = (Repeater)dli.FindControl("rptPromoCodesList");
                    reg.xref_reg_type_promo.Clear();
                    foreach (RepeaterItem ri in rptPromocodes.Items)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(((HiddenField)ri.FindControl("hdnCodeId")).Value);
                            DateTime? expires = null;

                            try
                            {
                                HiddenField exp = (HiddenField)ri.FindControl("hdnExpirationDate");
                                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(exp.Value))
                                    expires = Convert.ToDateTime(((HiddenField)ri.FindControl("hdnExpirationDate")).Value);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex) { }

                            var code = db.promo_code.Where(x => x.id == id).First();
                            reg.xref_reg_type_promo.Add(new xref_reg_type_promo
                            {
                                expiration = expires,
                                promoId = code.id
                            });
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) { }
                    }

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    ((HiddenField)dli.FindControl("hdnId")).Value = reg.id.ToString();

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                String err = ex.Message;
            }
        } 

    }
```

Comment: You have many empty catch blocks. These are a terrible practice. At least log some details or surface an error message if you're going to catch an exception. Don't have an empty catch block and don't just silently return from a catch block.

Comment: Good point. Will clean up my code once i get it working.

Comment: You should clean it up now because it could be hiding issues in your code.

Comment: Its not at all clear from your code that you ever Add a new invoice line (or whatever it is) so you reassign various data items, but never set the primary key to Null (or whatever) and add it to the underlying Linq DbSet. I presume Linq is just linking the existing row to the new invoice header table. Its difficult to tell with your code and not having any example of the data context structures.